# iPad Pro icon and launch image

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, ipad, air, icons

I'm developing an adobe air based app for iOS and I need to know the names for the recently added assets for iPad Pro - launch image(2048 x 2732) and icon (167x167). Unfortunately it's hard to guess their names based on previous ones.

Comment: I have the same problem, have you been able to find anything?

Comment: Fortunatelly for me it turned out to be some git "garbage" issue that corrupted the package, so it seems that iPad Pro resources aren't required yet. Still, I'm looking for an naswer to this.

Comment: Thanks for updating. Turns out I had a similar issue, where icons were not displayed due to an earlier internal version of an application being installed on the device. After re-installing via the App Store all the icons appear for me...

Answer (score 2):

I found that
Default-Landscape-1366h@2x.png
Default-Landscape-1366h.png
works for iPad Pro as launch images. They both should be 2732x2048.
Don't know if it suits portrait orientation. Also looking for correct icon names.

Comment: ...and the icon should be named Icon-167.png