# enabling iPad pro in xcode/simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, ios-simulator

I have an existing iPad project which I want to enable to be used on iPad-pro. In my "Project target" I set my "iOS Development Target" to 9.1 and made sure that in my individual app targets the same development target has been set. However when I choose iPad pro form the simulator and run the project my screen size is still set to the standard iPad size

```
the screen size:(0.0, 0.0, 768.0, 1024.0)
```

Could someone point me to what else I should be doing.

My project is a combination of objective-c and swift.
With thanks

Reza

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as with every iOS device that has a specific screen size, you have to provide the right launch image or a launch storyboard to make it known to iOS that you provide the screen size.

for ipad pro:

- https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html
- [iPad Pro launch image and App icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32875678/ipad-pro-launch-image-and-app-icon)
- [iPad Pro icon and launch image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32704337/ipad-pro-icon-and-launch-image)