# How do I make an iPad app scale for the iPad pro?

Tags: ios, ipad, ios-simulator, screen

I have been developing an iPad app using Xcode 7.3. When I test the app under the simulator for the iPad pro, it does not occupy the full screen (whereas it works fine on iPad 2).

Some posts on Apple forums indicate that it should, unless you are using a "native" mode, which I have not explicitly specified.

Is there a build setting somewhere I need to change?

Comment: duplicate:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33823576/enabling-ipad-pro-in-xcode-simulator

Comment: Actually, I think my question is asking the opposite. The "duplicate" is asking how to get the native resolution, and I am saying that I have it and I don't want it. Anyway, it led me to the answer, but with additional research required. I think the answer isn't particularly clear from the other issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem was caused because a launch screen file was specified rather than a launch image.

In Xcode, select the project and then the **General** tab and under **App Icons and Launch Images** there are two ways to specify the initial screen. You can add an image to your image catalogue (**launch image source**) or you can specify a storyboard or xib (**launch screen file**).

If you specify an image from the catalogue suitable for the iPad then when launching on an iPad pro it will scale the application. If you specify a launch screen file it will not scale.